# Удаление из таблицы строк по нескольким значениям в базе данных PostgreSQL

Tags: база-данных, postgresql

DELETE FROM table WHERE column = 134611654;

Удаляется только по этому значению. А есть множество значений, которые надо удалить, как написать запрос так, что бы брал и другие значения

Comment: `column IN (1, 3, 444, 100500)`

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE column in(?,?,?)
```